# how loop a command in terminal (from mkvmerge)

Tags: macos, loops, terminal

i have mkvmerge command but its only for one file
how can i loop it for all files in folder? (all files are mkv)

here is the command

```
/Applications/MKVToolNix-8.9.0.app/Contents/MacOS/mkvmerge --ui-language en_US --output '/Users/arashranjbar1/Downloads/[AC] Fairy Tail Complete [Dual Audio][BD][720p][Lucifer22]/Series/Fairy Tail - 001 (1).mkv' --language 0:und --track-name 0:AVC-HD --default-track 0:yes --language 1:eng --track-name 1:AAC --language 2:jpn --track-name 2:AAC --default-track 2:yes --language 3:eng --track-name 3:ASS --language 4:jpn --track-name 4:ASS --language 5:per --track-name 5:Persian --default-track 5:yes '(' '/Users/arashranjbar1/Downloads/[AC] Fairy Tail Complete [Dual Audio][BD][720p][Lucifer22]/Series/Fairy Tail - 001.mkv' ')' --track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2,0:5,0:3,0:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple loop should probably work:

```
for f in *.mkv
    do
        /Applications/MKVToolNix-8.9.0.app/Contents/MacOS/mkvmerge --ui-language en_US \
        --output "$f" --language 0:und --track-name 0:AVC-HD --default-track 0:yes \
        --language 1:eng --track-name 1:AAC --language 2:jpn --track-name 2:AAC \
        --default-track 2:yes --language 3:eng --track-name 3:ASS --language 4:jpn \
        --track-name 4:ASS --language 5:per --track-name 5:Persian \
        --default-track 5:yes '(' '"$f"' ')' --track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2,0:5,0:3,0:4
    done
```